# C++ char allocation

Tags: c++, memory, char

I'm using something like this:

```
char* s = new char;
sprintf(s, "%d", 300);
```

This works, but my question is why?

When I try to delete it I get an error so this produces a memory leak.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. It doesn't really work, your code is a bug. The fact that it produces an error when you try to delete should dispel any notion that it works.

Comment: My guess is that it's actually allocating either 4 or 8 bytes in place of the single byte character. This means that you get a bit of extra space over which you're allowed to trample without the OS or processor getting pissy. As juanchopanza said though, this is undefined behavior. Just because it works doesn't mean that it's correct or that it will work tomorrow. (It's also possible that you're just clobbering over some memory, and it doesn't cause any observable side affects. Memory allocation under the hood is not nearly as simple as `new`/`malloc` present it.)

Comment: @juanchopanza, but is this UB? everything is very defined right? It allocates a one char buffer, then writes to consecutive memory starting from that position. It is a buffer overrun. What might be undefined is *when* it actually bites you, because that depends on the memory allocator structure, and what memory was allocated before or afterwards... but that's not undefined behaviour, is more like randonness of the world.

Comment: @jsantander It is UB, plain and simple. No need to reason it out. The mode of failure might depend on implementation details, it might even seem not to fail sometimes. All of this gets absorbed into "undefined behaviour" as far as the standard is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It "works" because `sprintf` expects a `char*` as its first argument, and that what's you are giving him.

However, you really just allocated **one** `char` so writing more than one `char` to it is **undefined behavior**. It could be that more than one byte gets allocated depending on... the compiler, the host architecture, and so on but you can't rely on it. Actually, *anything* could happen and you don't want to base your code on such assumptions.

Either allocate more space for your string buffer, or better use a more "modern" approach. In your case it could be something like:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(300);
// Or, C++03
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(300);
```

(We are not talking about performance here, but the initial code being incorrect, we could hardly compare anyway).

As an added bonus, this code doesn't leak any memory because `std::string` takes care of freeing its internal memory upon destruction (`s` being allocated on the stack, this will happen automatically when it goes out of scope).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was trying to find out actually if the "undefined behaviour" can be explained in any way. I know that this use is wrong, but I wondered what happens to the memory. Are other variables overwritten in the process?

Comment: @ruff1991: It's **undefined** behavior, meaning **anything could happen**. I really mean it: it's impossible to tell what exactly is going to happen (especially as I don't know the specifics of your compiler, your host platform, and so on). Now, one might expect that in this case the memory located right after the `char` pointed to by `s` get overriden. But that's only a guess.

Comment: It depends on what is actually stored after your allocated memory block. If memory manager allocate bytes after your block to someone - then you can damage them. It depends on memory manager. User level memory manager(malloc/free) tries to be effective, so it preallocates chunks of memory(e.g. you ask for one byte, but memory manager will preallocate 16MB and slice it for futher allocations). If manager gives you last byte in it preallocated block - then writing after boundaries of this block will result in hardware exception(x86). Manager doesn't know your memory store/loads addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a one char buffer, then write to it with four chars ("300\0") [don't forget the string termination as I did] so the '3' goes into your allocated memory and the '0' and '0' and the '\0' goes to the next memory positions... that belong to someone else.

C++ does not do buffer overrun checking... so it works until it doesn't...

Comment: you forgot terminating \0

Comment: the example you give (don't check for the boundaries of the string) can be a security hole, right?